# Use ZAP or Burp suite to listen to https requests on public ip

Tags: zap, burp

I want to run ZAP or Burp suite on my ubuntu VPS and listen to the public server ip with changing the proxy settings in Firefox in my PC to the Server public ip and the listener port, as i see it's working fine with http requests but it's not working for https, how i can make it to listen to https requests?

I already configured the proxy in my browser and tried to disable HSTS in my browser

I tried to use nginx revers proxy and install certificate on the system and regenerate certificate and import it again on my browser, but no thing work :(

I am using `Ubuntu 18.4 with XFCE interface`

NOTE: As i said the problem it's not in my local machine, the problem it's in the remote ip address i have changed the listener ip to the public ip, that mean my burp or my zap installed on my VPS, that mean my vps is the proxy server, and my browser in my PC not in my VPS it's my own PC!

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you haven't configured your browser properly. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox you need to set http AND https proxy or check the box that says use the same for all...

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

i already did that, and installed the certificate and did every thing!

Comment: [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/functions/embedded-browser) and ZAP have an integrated pre-configured web browser. Burp: Intercepter -> Open Browser. ZAP: Browser Icon in the top-level toolbar. Might be a workaround.

Comment: As i said in the question the problem it's not in my local machine, the problem it's in the remote ip address i changed the listener ip to the public ip, that mean my burp or my zap installed on my VPS, that mean my vps is the proxy server, and my browser in my PC not in my VPS it's my own PC

Comment: Could be a local firewall issue on your VPS